# Formula for coefficients of interpolation polynomial

Tags: reference-request, interpolation, interpolation-theory

> (**Question**) What is the (conventional) formula for coefficients of interpolation polynomial?

Consider the interpolation problem: *find the polynomial through a given set of points* $(x_0,y_0),...,(x_n,y_n)$. Suppose we want the polynomial in canonical form (monomial basis): coefficients times powers of $x$.

Is there a standard solution to this problem? What would be the formula for the coefficients and how is it obtained?

*Note*: I found my [own solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826515/who-knows-this-formula-for-polynomial-interpolation) for this problem, but I would like to know the ‘standard’ solution. Maybe it involves some Linear Algebra that I am not aware of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general way to obtain it. Your unique polynomial will have to be of degree at most $n$, so assume we have 
$$p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + +\ldots + a_nx^n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k.$$

Then, plugging in your points, you get the equations
$$
y_i = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x_i^k, \quad \forall i \in [n].
$$
This is a linear system of $n+1$ equations in $n+1$ unknowns, guaranteed to be invertible due to the nature of the system. Hence, there is a unique solution, which you can find by Gaussian Elimination, for example.

**UPDATE - EXAMPLE**

Perhaps an example will help. Consider finding the unique linear polynomial through the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. We assume the form $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x$ which leads to the equations
$$
\begin{split}
0 = a_0 + a_1 \cdot 0\\
1 = a_0 + a_1 \cdot 1
\end{split}
$$
and the first equation simplifies to $a_0=0$, plugging into the second yields $a_1=1$, so we have $$p(x) = 0 + 1 \cdot x = x,$$
which is, of course, the unique line through $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, as expected.

Comment: How would you define $a_k$ specifically?

Comment: @Max you are not *defining* $a_k$, they are variables for which you are solving

Comment: Indeed, instead of define, I meant how do you get $a_k$ directly (so a formula for $a_k$).

Comment: @Max see update for an example. One can use something like Cramer's Rule if you insist on calculating coefficients directly via a formula instead of a general algorithmic procedure.

Comment: I would like the formula for $a_k$ in closed form. As used in the link.

Comment: @Max Please read up on Cramer's Rule I cited in the above comment. It is a closed form as you ask.

Comment: See also [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) which is a mechanical way of generating the polynomial through a set of given points (although it would need simplification to get to the form you want).

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks, I understand Cramer's rule but this would probably lead to exponential computing time.

Comment: @Max take a pick: elegant closed form with slow computation (Cramer's Rule) or cubic computation without closed form (Gaussian Elimination)

Comment: @Max +1, funny :)

Comment: If you don’t mind answering, how do we know that the system is invertible?

Comment: @Ovi you can reduce it to the Vandermonde matrix, which is known to always have non-zero determinant