# Prove the relation between divided differences and derivatives of a function

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

[Divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences) are defined like this:

\begin{align}
 [y_n] & = y_n \quad (1) \\
 [y_{n}, y_{n+1}] & = \dfrac{[y_{n+1}] - [y_n]}{x_{n+1} - x_n} \quad (2) \\
 [y_{n}, y_{n+1}, \dots, y_{n+k}] & = \dfrac{[y_{n+1}, y_{n+2}, \dots, y_{n+k}] - [y_{n}, y_{n+1}, \dots, y_{n+k-1}]}{x_{n+k} - x_n} \quad (3)
\end{align}

where $y_n = f(x_n)$.

See this answer [for the derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123427/newton-polynomial-divided-differences/3132961#3132961) of the above recursion. The question is how to connect the divided differences with function derivatives. Looking at the above equations, if we say

$x_{n+k} = x_n + kh$,

we can write

\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\to 0} [y_{n}, y_{n+1}] = [y_n,y_n] = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(x_n + h) - f(x_n)}{h} = f'(x_n) \quad (4)
\end{equation}

and from (4) and (3), we get

\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\to 0} [y_{n}, y_{n+1}, y_{n+2}] = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{[y_{n+1}, y_{n+2}] - [y_{n}, y_{n+1}]}{x_{n+2} - x_n} = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f'(x_n+h) - f'(x_n) }{2h} = \frac{ f''(x_n)}{2}
\end{equation}

I can go on and write this further and "see" that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\to 0} [y_{n}, y_{n+1}, y_{n+2}, \dots y_{n+k}] = \dfrac{f^k(x_n)}{k!} \quad (5)
\end{equation}

But how to prove this?

Using (3) I got this:

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0} [y_{n}, \dots y_{n+k}] & = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{[y_{n+1}, \dots, y_{n+k}]-[y_{n}, \dots, y_{n+k-1}]}{kh} \\
& = \lim_{h \to  0}\dfrac{\dfrac{[y_{n+2}, \dots, y_{n+k}]-[y_{n+1}, \dots, y_{n+k-1}]}{(k-1)h} - \dfrac{[y_{n+1}, \dots, y_{n+k-1}]-[y_{n}, \dots, y_{n+k-2}]}{(k-1)h} }{kh}
\end{align}

and got stuck here. I can see that if I were to write out recursively the fractions, I would continue to get $(k-l)$ for every level $l$, ultimately leading to (4), that can be back-substituted to give (5).

Another way might be to use [the polynomial interpolation error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_error):

$$f(x) - P_n(x) = \dfrac{f^{n+1}(\zeta)}{(n+1)!}\Pi_{i=0}^{n}(x-x_i) \quad   (6)$$

where $\zeta \in [x_0, \dots, x_n]$.

We can have $P_n(x)$ interpolate $f(x)$ over $[x_{n_0}, x_{n_1}, \dots x_{n_n}]$ using Hermite interpolation

$$P_n(x_{n_0}) = y_{n_0} $$

$$P_n'(x_{n_1}) = y'_{n_1} $$

$$P_n''(x_{n_2}) = y''_{n_2} $$

$$P_n^3(x_{n_3}) = y^3_{n_3} $$

$$\dots$$

$$P_n^n(x_{n_n}) = y^n_{n_n} $$

If $P_n(x)$ interpolates $f(x)$, then from (6), $\zeta = x_n$, so

$$f(x) - P_n(x) = \dfrac{f^{n+1}(x_n)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_{n})^{n+1} \quad (7)$$

We can extend the support with one more point $(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}), \tilde{x} \ne x_n$ and get a Newton polynomial extended by a term:

$$P_{n+1}(x) = P_n(x) + [y_{n_0},\dots,y_{n_n}, \tilde{y}](x-x_{n})^{n+1} \quad (8) $$

Inserting (8) into (7) we get

$$[y_{n_0},\dots,y_{n_n}, \tilde{y}] = \dfrac{f^{n+1}(\zeta)}{(n+1)!}, \quad \zeta \in [x_n, \tilde{x}]$$

and from this

$$[y_{n_0},\dots,y_{n_n}] = \dfrac{f^{n}(x_n)}{(n+1)!}$$

Is this fine?

What about the proof by induction?